# CSS / jQuery - Line break with css and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a script that hides the text, and that text is only displayed when the user hovers the mouse in the field

However, I was unable to break the text line, how could I do this?

Im using .net with razor

ScreenShots

[image: Without Mouse Hover]

[image: With Mouse Hover in the field]

View

```
<tr>
                <td colspan="10" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                    <div id="collapse_@(item.Id)" class="collapse in">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead class="thead-light">
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="11">
                                        Observações
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="6">

                                        <p class="txt-note">
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Observacao)
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

jQuery

```
function adjustFieldNote() {
    $('.txt-note').on('mouseover', function (e) {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.addClass("open");

    });

    $('txt-note').on('mouseout', function (e) {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.delay(1500).removeClass("open");
    })
}
```

CSS

```
.txt-note {
    width: 800px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break:break-all
}



.open{
    white-space: normal !important;
    overflow: unset !important;
    text-overflow: initial !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    word-break: break-all
}
```

Comment: you can use `word-wrap` facility in CSS. follow https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS snippet:

```css
.txt-note {
    width: 800px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`word-break: break-word` is depreciated. Use `word-break: break-all` instead.

[MDN: word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Instead of `word-wrap` (which is non-standard), use `overflow-wrap` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap).

> **From MDN:** The property was originally a nonstandard and unprefixed Microsoft extension called word-wrap, and was implemented by most browsers with the same name. It has since been renamed to overflow-wrap, with word-wrap being an alias.